# Functions Type (Injective and surjective)

Tags: functions

There are Injective and surjective functions and bijective if the function is both Injective and surjective. but what happened if a function is not Injective and surjective.
Is it a function?
Thanks

Comment: 'Is not injective and surjective', what do you mean by this? What is the scope of the negation? In any case a function is a function.

Comment: $f(x)=1/x$ is neither injective nor surjective.  (Think about 0.)  Is it a function?

Comment: @GitGud I mean not injective and not surjective

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an example: the function on from the set $\{1, 2, 3\}$ to $\{5, 6\}$ that sends all three of the domain elements to the single number $5$ in the codomain is a function, but it is neither injective (both $1$ and $2$ are sent to the same value, for example) nor surjective (no value is sent to $6$). But it's still a function, and indeed, functions like this one (so called "constant functions") arise a good deal in mathematics.

The reason for the definitions of injective, surjective, and bijective is that these are properties that come up pretty often, but not always. When they do, they can help you prove things; when they don't, the proofs are often harder. I believe that the main reason we care about "bijective" is that when a function is bijective, you can "invert" it, i.e., you can find a function that un-does what your function does. For instance, the function $f(x) = x + 3$ (from the reals to the reals) is bijective, and it has an inverse, namely $g(x) = x - 3$. But a function like $s(x) = x^2$ from the reals to the reals does not have an inverse. (You might think "what about square root"??? That's not a complete inverse. For instance, $s(-4) = 16$, but the square root function is defined to return the *nonnegative* square root of a nonnegative number, so it returns $4$ instead of $-4$.